# iTextSharp.tool.xml.exceptions.NoDataException For a filled <ul> list

Tags: c#, itext, html-lists, xmlworker

Trying to use ITextSharp XML Worker, and I've been getting the exception

> **iTextSharp.tool.xml.exceptions.NoDataException**

I have been combing through the HTML to work out what it's choking on, it's fine on my paragraphs / spans/ strongs / dels etc but with the following function:

```
public static void WriteHTML(PdfWriterChunk chunk, string html)
    {
        var CSS = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/PdfReport.css");
        var worker = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
        using (var ActionStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html)))
        {
            using (var cssFile = new FileStream(CSS, FileMode.Open))
            {
                worker.ParseXHtml(chunk.Writer, chunk.Document, ActionStream, cssFile);
            }

        }
    }
```

If I send the following (doing this in the immediate window):

```
var html = " <ul>          <li>              one          </li>          <li>              two          </li>          <li>              thyree          </li>          <li>              four          </li>      </ul>"

WriteHTML(chunk, html);
```

I get the exception. Surely the XML worker supports ul?? This is the HTML I am pasting into the above string for clarity:

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>thyree</li>
    <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

ITextSharp reports version as "5.5.10.0" (so does the XML worker)

my .css file literally just has "body {}"

is there something else I am doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

The exception didn't seem to matter, it adds the correct HTML to the PDF, I think I got confused because originally there was a "g" tag that was causing it to die that didnt add to the PDF. I am now using this function for anyone interested:

```
     public static void WriteHTML(PdfWriter writer,  Document document, string html)
    {
        //fixing error with g tag
        html = html.Replace("<g", "<span");
        html = html.Replace("/g>", "/span>");

        StringReader sr = new StringReader(html);
        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(
            writer, document, sr
        );

    }
```

Comment: When I added this to a fresh project, with a brand new doc. it worked fine. but that project got the version "5.5.12.0". So going to try upgrading

Comment: BAH upgrading did not solve the problem. This is so strange. the fresh project works with all of the HTML, the active one, chokes on the ul....

Comment: double BAH, the exception doesn't seem to matter, it still adds the correct stuff to the PDF!